# Extract .gz containing single .txt file in PHP using as little memory as possible

Tags: php, gzip

I have a file, `example.gz`, that contains a single file, `example.txt`. `example.txt` is a pretty big file and contains millions of lines.

What's the best way to go about extracting `example.gz` to my server while storing as little data in memory as possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

can't imagine a better approach than:

```
exec("gzip -d example.gz");
```

full path to file is usually a good idea.

Comment: Belated thank you, this worked perfectly and much faster than what I was already doing.